# Error CS0030 Cannot convert type 'char' to 'string'

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

Hi so am trying to get this to read a config string for a game am trying to make a plugin what rewards people who are on the list this is my error.

i tried multiple things am getting a bunch of different errors and i just cant figure out how to do this.

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0030  Cannot convert type 'char' to 'string'  PerkPlugin  C:\Users\f\Downloads\Smod2-master\Smod2-master\ExamplePlugin\PerkPlugin\PerkPlugin.cs   73  Active

```
using Smod2;

using Smod2.API;

using Smod2.Events;

using System;

namespace Smod.PerkPlugin
{
    class RoundStartHandler : IEventRoundStart
    {
        private Plugin plugin;
        private IConfigFile config;
        public RoundStartHandler(Plugin plugin)
        {
            this.plugin = plugin;
        }

        public void OnRoundStart(Server server)
        {

            string[] ItemString = new string[15];
            int[,,] ItemList = new int[15, 8, 16];
            int[] maxitem = new int[15];
            int[,] maxitemchance = new int[15, 8];

            ItemString[(int)Classes.CLASSD] = plugin.GetConfigString("default_item_classd");

            ItemString[(int)Classes.NTF_SCIENTIST] = plugin.GetConfigString("default_item_ntfscientist");

            ItemString[(int)Classes.SCIENTIST] = plugin.GetConfigString("default_item_scientist");

            ItemString[(int)Classes.CHAOS_INSUGENCY] = plugin.GetConfigString("default_item_ci");

            ItemString[(int)Classes.NTF_LIEUTENANT] = plugin.GetConfigString("default_item_lieutenant");

            ItemString[(int)Classes.NTF_COMMANDER] = plugin.GetConfigString("default_item_commander");

            ItemString[(int)Classes.NTF_GUARD] = plugin.GetConfigString("default_item_guard");

            ItemString[(int)Classes.TUTORIAL] = plugin.GetConfigString("default_item_tutorial");

            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < 16; k++)
                    {
                        ItemList[i, j, k] = -1;
                    }
                }
                if (ItemString[i] != "-1" && ItemString[i] != null)
                {
                    ItemString[i].Replace(" ", string.Empty);
                    string[] items = ItemString[i].Split(',');
                    for (maxitem[i] = 0; maxitem[i] < items.Length; maxitem[i]++)
                    {
                        string[] itemchance = items[maxitem[i]].Split(':');
                        for (maxitemchance[i, maxitem[i]] = 0; maxitemchance[i, maxitem[i]] < itemchance.Length; maxitemchance[i, maxitem[i]]++)
                        {
                            ItemList[i, maxitem[i], maxitemchance[i, maxitem[i]]] = System.Convert.ToInt32(itemchance[maxitemchance[i, maxitem[i]]]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (Player player in server.GetPlayers())
            {
                string playerIP = player.IpAddress;
                string[] playerIPSplit = playerIP.Split(':');
                playerIP = (playerIPSplit.Length >= 1 ? playerIPSplit[playerIPSplit.Length - 1] : playerIP).Trim();
                string perks = plugin.GetConfigString("perk_ips");
                foreach (string perkIP in plugin.GetConfigString("perk_ips"))
                {
                    string[] perkIPSplit = perkIP.Split(':');
                    string endperkIP = (perkIPSplit.Length >= 1 ? perkIPSplit[perkIPSplit.Length - 1] : perkIP).Trim();

                    if (playerIP.Equals(endperkIP))
                    {


                        int classtype = (int)player.Class.ClassType;
                        if (classtype > -1 && classtype < 15)
                        {
                            foreach (Item item in player.GetInventory())
                            {
                                item.Remove();
                            }

                            for (int i = 0; i < maxitem[classtype]; i++)
                            {
                                Random rd = new Random();
                                int result = ItemList[classtype, i, rd.Next(0, maxitemchance[classtype, i])];
                                if (result != -1)
                                {
                                    player.GiveItem((ItemType)result);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }


                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Please don't post a wall of code and an error message without any indication of where the error is happening. The error seems pretty clear though. What do you not understand about it?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this line:

```
foreach (string perkIP in plugin.GetConfigString("perk_ips"))
```

has you iterating over a string, which results in a character.  It appears that `GetConfigString` doesn't return a collection of strings, but only a single string.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue and the answer above gave me the idea to try this, so instead of

```
foreach (string perkIP in plugin.GetConfigString("perk_ips"))
```

you could try

```
foreach (var perkIP in plugin.GetConfigString("perk_ips"))
```

then in the portion where perkIp appears you just convert it from char to string

```
perkIp.ToString()
```

example like here:

```
string[] perkIPSplit = perkIP.Split(':');

string endperkIP = (perkIPSplit.Length >= 1 ? perkIPSplit[perkIPSplit.Length - 1] : perkIP).Trim();
```

to

```
string[] perkIPSplit = perkIP.ToString().Split(':');
string endperkIP = (perkIPSplit.Length >= 1 ? perkIPSplit[perkIPSplit.Length - 1] : perkIP.ToString()).Trim();
```